# prove that $a^{nb}-1=(a^n-1)((a^n)^{b-1}+...+1)$

Tags: number-theory

Prove that $a^{nb}-1=(a^n-1)\cdot ((a^n)^{b-1}+(a^n)^{b-2}+...+1)$

We can simplify it, like this:
$$(a^{n})^b-1=(a^n-1)\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{b}(a^{n})^{b-i}$$

How can we prove this?

Comment: Use the (simpler) fact that $x^b-1 = (x-1)(x^{b-1} + \dots + 1)$ and replace $x$ by $a^n$.

Comment: Induction on $b$ is easy enough

Comment: @OldJohn , do you if there is a post of that fatc?

Comment: I am sure it has been asked on this site - I will see if I can find a link. But it is very easy to prove - just use the formula for the sum of a geometric progression, for example.

Comment: This is called telescopic sum. Search under that term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(x-y)\sum_{i=1}^n(x^{i-1}y^{n-i})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x^{i}y^{n-i}-x^{i-1}y^{n-i+1})=\sum_{i=1}^nx^{i}y^{n-i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^{i-1}y^{n-i+1}=\sum_{i=1}^nx^{i}y^{n-i}-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^{(i+1)-1}y^{n-(i+1)+1}=\sum_{i=1}^nx^{i}y^{n-i}-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^{i}y^{n-i}=x^n-y^{n}$ 
Substitute appropriately...

Comment: Wow, that is even more general, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
&(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+x^{n-3}+\dots+x+1)\\
=&\quad\,x^n+x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+x^{n-3}+\dots+x\\
&\quad\quad\;\:\,-x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}-x^{n-3}-\dots-x-1\\
=&\quad\,x^n\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\;\;\;-1
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

For $\ x = a^b\ $ it is $\ f_n \,:=\, \dfrac{x^n-1}{x-1}\, =\, x^{n-1}+ x^{n-2} +\cdots  + x + 1.\,$ Here is a proof by [telescopy.](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3amath.stackexchange.com+%28Dubuque+OR+%22math+gems%22+OR+%22key+ideas%22%29+%28telescopy+OR+telescopic%29)
Notice that $\ \color{#0a0}{f_{n} - f_{n-1} = x^{n-1}}\ $ since $\ \dfrac{x^n-1}{x-1} - \dfrac{x^{n-1}-1}{x-1}\, =\, \dfrac{x^n-x^{n-1}}{x-1\quad }\, =\, x^{n-1}$
$\begin{eqnarray}{\rm\! Hence}\ \  &&\qquad\quad\ \ \, \underbrace{\color{#0a0}{f_n}} \\
\,&=&\ \ \overbrace{\color{#0a0}{x^{n-1}}\ \ \ \ \ \ +\ \ \ \ \ \  \underbrace{\color{#0a0}{f_{n-1}}}}\\
\,&=&\ \ x^{n-1} +\  \overbrace{{x^{n-2}\ \ \ \  \ \,+\,\ \ \ \ \ \underbrace{f_{n-2}}}}\\
\,&=&\ \ x^{n-1} +\ x^{n-2}+\ \overbrace{x^{n-3}\ \ \ \ +\ \ \ \ {f_{n-3}}}\\
\,&&\qquad\qquad\ \ \vdots\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\ddots
\end{eqnarray}$
Alternatively we can write it in [telescopic form](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3amath.stackexchange.com+%28Dubuque+OR+%22math+gems%22+OR+%22key+ideas%22%29+%28telescopy+OR+telescopic%29)

$\ \ \begin{eqnarray}
\color{#c00}{f_n-f_k}\, =\, 
\underbrace{\phantom{f_n-f_{n-1}}}_{\Large x^{n-1}}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!{\color{#c00}{f_n}}&&\!\!\overbrace{{-f_{n-1}} 
+\underbrace{\phantom{f_{n-1} - f_{n-2}}}_{\Large x^{n-2}}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!f_{n-1}}^{=\, 0}&&\!\!\overbrace{-f_{n-2} + f_{n-2} }^{=\, 0}
- \,\cdots\, \overbrace{-f_{k+2} 
+ \underbrace{\phantom{f_{k+2} - f_{k+1}}}_{\Large x^{k+1}}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!f_{k+2}}^{=\, 0}&&\!\!\overbrace{-f_{k+1}
+\underbrace{\phantom{f_{k+1} - f_{k}}}_{\Large x^{k}}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!f_{k+1}}^{=\,0}&&\!\!\!\color{#c00}{-\,f_k}\\
\end{eqnarray}$

Comment: Note: I swapped $\,n\,$ and $\,b\,$ in the OPs notation.